# Adding multiple rows or column in body

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

Hi trying to figure out why my hamburger is getting misaligned when i add another `Expanded()` code within the body.

I tried to follow this url to develop a hamburger menu and responsive for all platforms at once.
[Flutter Blog](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/building-a-responsive-ui-architecture-in-flutter/)

Below is the code that i tried where i added `Expanded()` below the `Row()`

```
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.menu, size: 30),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: width,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Lottie.network(
                        'https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/6WfDdm3ooQTEs1L/data.json'),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            "Multivariate Testing",
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontSize: 50,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            'Run experiments to make key flows more effective.',
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontSize: 25,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 35,
                        ),
                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            'Create Experiment',
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the output that i am seeing from mobile view. Appreciate any help. Sorry for too big screenshot! [image: MobileView Output from above code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the default functionality of `Row`.

So change your first child for your top level `Row` to this,

```
Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  drawer: AppDrawer(),
  body: Row(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu, size: 30),
                onPressed: () {
                  _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                })),
      ),
      Expanded( ...... rest of your code
```

Here, we are using the `Align` widget with `alignment: Alignment.topCenter`.

`Align` widget takes the entire available space in the parent and then depending on the `alignment` property, aligns it't child inside it.

So, saying `Alignment.topCenter` will place it at the top vertically and middle horizontally.

Using an `AppBar` will unnecessarily complicate your situation since now, the `AppBar` is going to take up space a the top, but in your case, you want your `Lottie` view to be visible at the top, so it will overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Because Expanded fills up the whole space and that's why your hamburger is getting misaligned.
Why don't you try using appbar for the hamburger?

Comment: Hi I will take a look at appbar, but for the other part ```Expanded()``` I tried changing it to ```Row()``` it didnt work for me

Comment: You dont't need to change the Expanded() to Row(). Just align the first child to top like @nisanth-reddy has suggested in his answer.